# Why does my find_in_set match for a single value only and not for comma separated values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem in `matching` with `find_in_set`; it does not matches for multiple comma separated values.

**Below is what i have tried**

```
$skills = array('php','html','laravel','nodejs');

$skills = implode(',', $skills);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs_posted_by_employer WHERE FIND_IN_SET(skills, :array)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam('array', $skills);
```

For this table, the above query...

```
+-----------------------+
|        skills         |
+-----------------------+
|        php            |   => matches
+-----------------------+
| php,laravel,html      |   => does not match--why?
+-----------------------+
|       html            |   => matches
+-----------------------+
|php,html,laravel,nodejs|   => does not match -- why?
+-----------------------+
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Normalize your data.  Avoid storing CSV in your table if possible.  You can't use `FIND_IN_SET` this way.

Comment: I think find_in_set is to work for finding single value in comma separated values, you are searching for comma separated values in the comma separated values. Am I making sense?

Comment: @rahulsm, ya want to `match` on `comma` seperated. yes you are right

Comment: But it is not possible using find_in_set as per your requirement

Comment: @rahulsm,  then how would i go about it?

Comment: Please clarify by editing your question, not in comments. Read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Goutham, you can do what you want by using a loop in PHP to build a set of OR statements that takes each element of your string array and creates successive individual find_in_set statements with an OR between them. What you want to end up with is a query that checks for each element in your array, against the set. And don't implode your array into a string, because you need to use it as an array.

```
$skills = array('php','html','laravel','nodejs');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs_posted_by_employer WHERE ";
for($x=0;$x<count($skills);$x++){
    if($x>0){$sql .=" OR ";}
    $sql .=" WHERE FIND_IN_SET(".$skills[$x].", :array)";
}
$sql .=";";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam('array', $skills);
```

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand how `FIND_IN_SET` works.

- `FIND_IN_SET('html', 'php,html,laravel,nodejs')` is true, because the string `'html'` is in the set `'php,html,laravel,nodejs'`.
- `FIND_IN_SET('php,laravel,html', 'php,html,laravel,nodejs')` is false, because the string `'php,laravel,html'` is not in the set `'php,html,laravel,nodejs'`.

Don't store values separated in a database table column. Have a separate table to link the single skills to each `jobs_posted_by_employer` record in order to query the data easily.

Comment: ya you are right but i want to `match` any value `against` 'php,html,laravel,nodejs'  with above example it has to match all the values in my table

Comment: So you would need a function that builds the intersection of the sets (which would be `'html,php'` for `'php,laravel,html'` and `'php,html,laravel,nodejs'`) and check whether the result is empty or not. Such function is not available. Maybe it's possible to write such function in MySQL; I don't know. Anyway, in a relational database you should never store comma-separated values, but normalize your tables instead. SQL is not designed to muddle through strings.